# Linux script that indicates time the server was offline?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Below is data taken from my dedicated server:

```
root@namhost [~]# last
root     pts/0        XXX Tue May 18 09:46   still logged in
root     pts/0        XXX Mon May 17 08:51 - 12:18  (03:26)
reboot   system boot  XXX Mon May 17 08:49         (1+00:59)
root     pts/0        XXX Sun May 16 11:50 - 13:15  (01:25)

root@namhost [~]# last | grep "system boot"
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-164.15.1. Mon May 17 08:49         (1+01:02)
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-164.el5   Tue May 11 04:20         (7+05:31)
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-164.el5   Tue May 11 03:53         (7+05:58)
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-128.el5   Mon Oct  5 22:40          (-3:-50)
....
```

I need a script that I can run on an hourly basis that will:
 1. Calculate the total downtime since the first date
 2. The overall downtime percentage
 3. Store this data in a file at /home/bla/file.txt, in the following format:
    TotalDowntime=03:02:02
    Average=0.01%

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: what do you mean by downtown, are you referring to time that no one is logged in and using the system, by CPU, or when the computer is off?

Comment: Computer is off.

Comment: Nagios or Zenoss is monitoring software that can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to figure out when your system was shut down (and I'm not sure why a server would be down at all other than a problem), you can try the following (though I'm sure theres got to be a much better way):

1. Create a folder somewhere to log stuff (perhaps /var/downtime_logs/)
2. Create a cronjob to touch a file in that folder `` touch /var/downtown_logs/`date +%s` `` every minute (or use `$(date +%s)` in order to [avoid using backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082))
3. Then count the number of files in that folder
4. If you compare the date of the first file to the current date, that's how much time you've been keeping stats for and you can do some math to get the rest

I've left this as a community wiki for other people to chime in and finish the rest

Comment: I presume instead of "test +%s" you mean "date +%s". Also, you would need to clean that directory out once in a while. That would create about 43,200 files per month.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my post Dennis. You're right about the clean up, but I just got lazy at the end and just wanted to provide a general approach. Devils in the detail.

Comment: Hmm... What about creating the file at startup with "touch /var/downtown_logs/`date +%s`" and store the path in an enviorment variable. Then update it's timestamp every minute with "touch $enVarName". Then you have a file for each time the computer booted up, and it's timestap tells you when it shut down.

Comment: Have to be careful about the `%` char in a [cron entry](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?crontab). Usually escaping it with a backslash works

Answer (score 1):

There's [downtimed](http://dist.epipe.com/downtimed/) for this purpose.